# Migrating a small app from rails 3.1.3 to 3.1.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I'am trying to migrate a rails app from 3.1.3 to 3.1.10

I changed 3.1.3 to 3.1.10 in the gemfile and the ran `bundle update rails`

Despite the gemfile being almost empty, i have the following error:

> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "multi_json":   In
>   Gemfile:
>       uglifier (>= 1.0.3) ruby depends on
>         multi_json (~> 1.3) ruby
>
> ```
> rails (= 3.1.10) ruby depends on
>   multi_json (1.2.0)
> ```

here is my gemfile :

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.10'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'rails_admin'
gem 'devise'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'sass-rails',   '3.1.5'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'therubyracer'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
#gem for images
gem 'paperclip'
```

Uglifier is a gem present by default, how can a gem added by rails 3.1.3 needs a more recent one that the one 3.1.10 needs(1.2.0) !

How can i migrate?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you are trying to downgrade versions. `3.1.3` is more recent than `3.1.10`. That is why `3.1.3` requires a more recent version.

Comment: rails 3.1.10 does not even have a dependency on multi_json?! https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions/3.1.10

Answer (score 0):

create a new project. Then edit the new gem file to reflect new rails version. Copy contents of old gem file to new one except for rails. Perform bundle install. Copy old project into new project. Bundle it and again perform rake db:migrate.

Hope this helps.